# Capturing Date using Date and Time from Expression builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, date, datetime

I have a string that includes date and time like in this format: '23/02/2021 09:03', '24/02/2021 09:10' etc. I would like to use Rule based filtering to colour symbols that has `date=23/02/2021`. So idea is use different colour symbols for different dates to show in QGIS.

I am stuck while using the Date and Time in Expression builder would require some tips on how to use it or if there is another way to filter and apply rule based labelling.

Answer (score 5):

The proper round-trip to creating an actual `datetime` type and then format the date string, would be

```
format_date( to_datetime( "<date_column_name>", 'd/M/yyyy hh:mm' ), 'd/MM/yyyy' )
```

You could also simply split the string, e.g.

```
left( "<date_column_name>", 10 )
```

if the format is *always* `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`.

Alternatively, using that you could also create a `date` type and use it directly:

```
to_date( left( <date_column_name>, 10 ), 'd/M/yyyy' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have formatted your dates as `sting`. In this case, you should convert it to a `date` or `datetime` format. For the example you provided, you can create a new field with field calculator in `date` format (without time) using this expression:

```
to_date( 
right (left (time,10),4) || '-'  || 
right (left (time, 5),2) || '-' || 
left (time,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibility. The first is to extract the first 10 character from your string to get only the date without the time. So if your text field that hold the date is named "DATE_TEXT" you could use the expression :  `left(  "DATE_TEXT" ,10) = '23/02/2021'` for the rule (and of course add as many rule as you need by changing the date)

The second solution is to convert your text field (in this exemple named "DATE_TEXT") to a date time field : create a new field or use a virtual field (in this exemple I named it "DATE_TIME") then use the field calculator with the expression :  `to_datetime(  "DATE_TEXT" , 'd/M/yyyy HH:mm')`.

This second solution offer the advantage to let you work with real date so you can symbolize your data using comparison  ( date older/newer than a set date) while this will not work (or more exactly may give you wrong result) if you use string format.

Below a picture synthetising both solution
[image]